# Convert ipv4 & ipv6 both into number

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
INET_ATON()
```

Return the numeric value of an IP address

```
INET6_ATON()
```

Return the numeric value of an IPv6 address

i have a column contain ipv4 & ipv6 both.

I try to convert those to number 'ip_long'(column's name)

I use `INET_ATON,` it only convert ipv4

My question is, does `INET6_ATON` convert ipv6 only or both?

Is any function can convert both? I have million rows in db need to convert.

Comment: INET6_ATON is available in MySQL 5.6 & above and from the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton it should also return the value of IPv4. To confirm please check SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9') as ip4, INSET6_ATON('10.0.5.9') as ip6; I could not test it as I do not have  the latest version of MySQL installed.

Comment: or is any way to do it in php?

Comment: Didn't you test in MySQL? I think it should work. If you are interested in PHP and your objective is to convert the IP to number then please go through this http://www.samclarke.com/2011/07/php-ipv6-to-128bit-int/.

Comment: i test in mysql, its not working, im thinking to upgrade mysql to 5.7

Comment: Upgrading to 5.7 won't do you any good. For one it's not released yet, for two it won't fix your problem. Double check, if you're providing correct IPv4 values to `INET6_ATON()`

Answer (score 4):

`INET6_ATON()` will convert both ipv4 and ipv6. As you already know, you need MySQL version 5.6.x or higher.

The catch is to use only `INET6_ATON()` and `INET6_NTOA()`. The column which will store the the converted IPs will be of `VARBINARY(16)` type.

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(INET6_ATON("192.168.1.1"));

SELECT INET6_NTOA(INET6_ATON("2001:db8::1"));
```

Remember that the `ip` column from test_table is VARBINARY(16);

Comment: Been doing a lot of research on this lately and this is the first time I've seen that the application should add a `"::FFFF:"` before the IPv4. Why do we need to do that? Doesn't say that in the doc.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton

Comment: @Draven. I've used "::FFFF:" to map an IPv4 to IPv6 in an application which had to listen for both IPv4 and IPv6 connections (you know, a dual stack node), but anyway, you are right. MySQL is pretty smart at storing and correctly retrieving  an IPv4 address to and from a VARBINARY column. I will edit my answer. Cheers!